# converting object to string in java and excluding unnecessary characters

Tags: java, json

I am creating on Json from one java object and convert it to string format this code

```
new JSONObject(responseDTO.getDTOHeader()).toString();
```

But results with string with unexpected characters.For example

```
"{\"languageID\":0,\"test1\":14,\"loginID\":\"LKS280\",\"errorCategory\":0,\"replyTopic\":null,\"errorCode\":0,\"sessionType\":null,\"sessionKey\":\"LKS2801409739957847\",\"creationTime\":\"Wed Sep 03 15:55:57 IST 2014\",\"messageType\":3,\"version\":\"1.0.0\"}
```

How can I exclude \"

Comment: Can you tell us what is `responseDTO.getDTOHeader()` returning?

Comment: `String.replace("\", "");`

Comment: @bigdestroyer what if the key or value contains "\" ?

Comment: Actually, the character is `\"` (escape sequence). Why do you want to remove it?

Comment: responseDTO.getDTOHeader() returns object

Comment: If the value contains \ ,it causes error in front end

Comment: `StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); jsonObj.write(sw);` instead of `jsonObj.toString()` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle it on client side using  [Json.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Pass above `Java String` as `JavaScript String` then `parse` that `String` on client side

```
var str="{\"languageID\":0,\"test1\":14,\"loginID\":\"LKS280\",\"errorCategory\":0,\"replyTopic\":null,\"errorCode\":0,\"sessionType\":null,\"sessionKey\":\"LKS2801409739957847\",\"creationTime\":\"Wed Sep 03 15:55:57 IST 2014\",\"messageType\":3,\"version\":\"1.0.0\"}";

var obj=JSON.parse(str);  //parse string to json
```

Here's the demo fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/e26t6LjL/

**or**

Replace all `\` whith `""`

```
new JSONObject(responseDTO.getDTOHeader()).toString().replaceAll("\\","");
```

Comment: This will also remove escaped backslashes inside the data. You need to make the replace more specific.

Comment: How about handle it on client side using `Json.parse()`